# How do you code that if you enter a number into <input>m the number is compared to an if-clause?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

so basically my html input looks like this

```
<input class="inputfield" id="heartrate">
```

In my script i refer to it by

```
const myHr = document.getElementById("heartrate")
```

And then i Want, that if you wirte a number into the inputfield a basic alert window opens with string

```
myHr.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
    if (event.which === KEY_ENTER && myHr.value === 80){
        alert("Your heart rate is perfect")
    } 
})
```

I tried it with innerText too, but it doesnt work. Obviously it has something to do with the way the input is collected, but i have no idea.

Comment: what is `KEY_ENTER`, and value is a string, not a number. so `"80" === 80` is false

Comment: oh sorry, "KEY_ENTER = 13" so if the user inputs 80, it is a string? how do you change that, i know you can do parseInt() but how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `event.key` and remember to cast element `.value` to number using `Number()`

```js
const myHr = document.getElementById("heartrate")

myHr.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && Number(myHr.value) === 80) {
    alert("Your heart rate is perfect")
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="inputfield" id="heartrate">
```

---

#### Reference

[KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) (Properties > `value`)

Comment: thanks alot! can you explain to me what exactly Number() does? Does it convert what is in the () into a number so my strict comparision then works?

Comment: @TimoNeske Right. `.value` return a DOMString for you, so when you use strict comparision operator `===`, it would return `false`. So using `Number(...)` will cast it to number and comparision would work as expected

Answer (score 0):

Problem you have is an explicit equals. An input's value is a string and you are comparing it to a number. So you need to convert the string to a number. You can use parseInt(), parseFloat(), Number(), or +.

```js
const myHr = document.getElementById("heartrate")

const KEY_ENTER = 13;

myHr.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
  if (event.which === KEY_ENTER && +myHr.value === 80) {
    alert("Your heart rate is perfect")
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="inputfield" id="heartrate">
```

Modern day JavaScript uses key and not which

```js
const myHr = document.getElementById("heartrate")

myHr.addEventListener("keypress", () => {
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && +myHr.value === 80) {
    alert("Your heart rate is perfect")
  }
})
```

```html
<input class="inputfield" id="heartrate">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Constants_for_keyCode_value please include this link too